# SharePoint List exporting differently to excel display

Tags: 2016, export-to-excel

We have recently upgraded to SP 2016.
Our excel reports extract data from linked SharePoint lists.
Following the upgrade, the lists display fine in SharePoint, however are disjointed in excel with some fields being omitted.
Initial investigation from our dev team points to columns which have linked items, wasnt an issue before, has anyone experienced this please?
Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After engaging with Microsoft, it appears to be a compatibility issue between MSO (16.0.4266.1001) and SharePoint 2016.
Update your excel version to minimum (16.0.4993.1002) to resolve.